# KML mystery of the unmappable address

Tags: python, xml, google-maps, kml

using python i am generating a KML file from a csv file containing lat/long values. i am using this example:

http://l0u15.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/convert-csv-to-kml-for-google-maps/

when i map this:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Disney's Hollywood Studios</name>
    <description>Disney's Hollywood Studios is a theme park at the Walt Disney World Resort. Spanning 135 acres in size, its theme is show business, drawing inspiration from the heyday of Hollywood in the 1930s and 1940s. The third park built at the resort, it opened on May 1, 1989 as Disney-MGM Studios. In 2007, the park hosted approximately 9.51 million guests.</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-81.561995,28.357403</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

it works without a problem! however this:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Beyond Basics Medical Practice</name>
    <description>213031 321 Middlefield Rd Ste 275 Menlo Park CA 94025 (650) 815-9577 1/4/2012 San Francisco Unknown</description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-122.168048,37.456523</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

does not show up at all!

is there some kind of indentation requirement for KML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. [Here it is in Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Ftestkml_placemark_A_kml.xml&hl=en&ll=37.456522,-122.167955&spn=0.001275,0.001725&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=41.546728,56.513672&t=m&z=19&iwloc=lyrftr%3akml%3acjy5Wd1IV6vbsEDb7g4q2O-TQLrhN4t5XxLDo6pUJ,g061ebc8ce23201c9,37.456524,-122.168049,0,-32) - [both points](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Ftestkml_placemark_B_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=37.456522,-122.167955&sspn=0.001275,0.001725&t=m&z=4)

[and here in the Google Maps API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=testkml_placemark_A_kml.xml) - [both points](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=testkml_placemark_B_kml.xml)

Comment: You didn't say anything about together.  But that works also.  I would suggest you post the complete kml that is giving you problems.

Comment: I REALIZED I DIDNT USE THE DOCUMENT TAG AT ALL. sorry for caps